# Post request returns undefined on the server side

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, node.js, post

So, I have this POST request I made

```
$("#pacotes").on('click', ".produto", function () {
    console.log(this.id);
    $.post("http://localhost:3000/pacote?idPacote=" + this.id);
});
```

The log returns a number on the client side, as it should.

The post then goes through my route and arrives here

```
exports.Pacote = function (req, res) {
    console.log("gato");
    var pacote = req.idPacote;
    console.log(pacote);
    connection.connection();
    global.connection.query('SELECT * FROM Pacote WHERE idPacotes = ? LIMIT 1', [pacote], function (err, result) {
    if (result.length > 0) {
         if (result) {
              var object = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
              var packObject = object[0];
              if (result.length > 0) {
              if (result) {
                   res.render('home', { title: 'pacote', layout: 'pacote', data: packObject  });
              }
         }   
     } else if (err) {
      console.log(err);
     }
   };
   });
}
```

The first log is just a flag to see if it is reaching the point, which it is
But the second log should return a number, yet it is returning undefined

I'm not very experienced in this subject, but this has always worked for me.
I don't understand where I went differently as my login function is nearly the same thing and returns actual values as expected. Maybe because of bodyparser, but I dont know.

It just bothers me that the id returns properly on the client side but as undefined on the server side

I also tried the same thing but with GET and the results didnt change

Comment: Please post your route definition here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing "idPacote" in query string. You will get the the query string parameters in "req.query" if you are using Express with NodeJS. Try this

```
var pacote = req.query.idPacote;
```

instead of

```
var pacote = req.idPacote;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `var pacote = req.idPacote;` should be replaced with (provided that you send it as `GET` parameter):

```
var pacote = req.params.idPacote;
```

A side note: you should be using **connection pooling** in order to improve performance in your app, for example:

```
var mysql = require("mysql");    
//Database connection parameters
var config = {
    connectionLimit: 10000, 
    host: "127.0.0.1",
    user: "user",
    password: "password",
    database: "database",
    charset: "utf8_general_ci",
    connectTimeout: 4000
};   
//Pool
var pool  = mysql.createPool(config);           
function connection(){
    //Assign connection pool for further reuse
    this.init = function () {       
        this.pool = pool;       
    };
    //Get connection
    this.acquire = function(callback){      
        this.pool.getConnection(function(error, con){
            if (error) {
                if (this.pool) 
                    //Close all connections in pool
                    this.pool.end(function(err){});
                console.log("\x1b[31m" + error, "\x1b[0m");             
            }
            else {
                callback(error, con);
            }
        });         
    };
}
```

Read more [here](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections).